# Scala child class fails to recognize a generic map in the parent?

Tags: scala, inheritance

I have the a code snippet which looks as follows:

```
abstract class MultipleOutputWriter {
  protected def writers: collection.mutable.Map[Any, OutputStream]
  def write(basePath: String, value: Any)
  def close = writers.values.foreach(_.close)
}
class LocalMultipleOutputWriter extends MultipleOutputWriter {
  protected val writers = collection.mutable.Map[String, FileOutputStream]()
  def write(key: String, value: Any) = {
    //some implementation
  }
}
```

However upon compilation it throws a type mismatch between parent class and derived class `writers`. Why does this happen? Does the scala compiler not check that the map parameters are sub-types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala maps are Invariant in the key type, thus `Map[String, _]` has no type relation to `Map[Any, _]`

[Map documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map)

> `trait Map[A, +B]`

Note that there is no variance marker on `A`, therefore it's invariant.

You could parameterize it:

```
abstract class MultipleOutputWriter[K, V <: OutputStream] {
  protected def writers: collection.mutable.Map[K, V]
  def write(basePath: String, value: Any)
  def close = writers.values.foreach(_.close)
}
class LocalMultipleOutputWriter extends MultipleOutputWriter[String, FileOutputStream] {
  protected val writers = collection.mutable.Map[String, FileOutputStream]()
  def write(key: String, value: Any) = {
    //some implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I marked it correct prematurely. I tried what you said and it still gives me the following: `overriding method writers in class MultipleOutputWriter of type => scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,java.io.OutputStream];
value writers has incompatible type
protected val writers = collection.mutable.Map[String, FileOutputStream]()`

Comment: You probably need to parameterize the V as well. Updating